# How can I make web link in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, dialog, android-alertdialog

I added an Action button to show about Alert Dialog for my app that I'm developing.... I just fetched one xml file for that Action Dialog popup.

I used this xml as Alert Dialog popup. using below java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click the links below to contact us"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wa"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/info"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fb"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wa"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

java code :

```
public void info(MenuItem item) {


View v = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.alertdiag, null);
TextView waf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wa);
TextView fbf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fb);


AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

builder.setMessage("About");
builder.setView(v);
builder.setCancelable(false);


builder.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Now I can see those TextViews in my main activity as alert Dialog. But I can't click the links. Any solution????

Thank you in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Use  `AlertDialog.setView()` to display a custom layout containing your hyperlink TextView in the message area.

E.g. Make a **hyperlink_layout.xml** containing a `TextView` with `id = hyperlink_text`

Comment: I got you. I've sucessfully inflated custom layout into AlertDialog. but the hyperlink text is unclickable.....

Comment: If I do anything to click hyperlink in AlertDialog and run the app It automatically kills the entire app when I click Info button on Action bar.